Woocommerce string change as translation
My whole Wordpress based webshop (woocommerce based) is fine languagewise, except two buttons on product pages, which contain more images, and uses the wc gallery function.
E.g. https://retroladymode.hu/termek/retrolady-nika-sportcipo-egyet-fizet-kettot-kap/ this page, which shows english Previous and Next buttons.
Thanks!

I have checked all plugins' all language files. All of them are fine.

I have tried to modify the buttons' innerHTML with js.

Any other solutions...?



Did you try the gettext filter hook like in those threads (targeting single product pages with is_product())?

Using js you can modify the text but you need wp_localize_script to make your strings translatable. There are many examples how to use wp_localize_script
